# Is it posible to generate SNARK of MPC share validity?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, snarks

Assume we have a central issuing authority that sends each participant a share that reconstructs in key $P_k$. I.e. Shamir Secret Share with $2$ out of $N$ format where $N>3$.

This central authority also broadcasts public key $P_a$ so every participant guaranteed to receive same $P_a$.

Is it possible to generate such a proof, that participants can be sure that shares they receive indeed reconstruct in to $P_k$ (which constructs $P_a$) without showing their shards to each other?
Can SNARKs handle such a task?

Comment: I guess SNARK can be qualified for the task. But, CA should generate  different proofs for different participants, each proof is $\pi_{i^*} := \prod .Prove(crs, P_a, (\{P_{k,i}\}_{i\in {N-1}},P_{k,i^*}))$ where $P_{k,i^*}$ is known to the party $i^*$.

Comment: Yes individual proofs for each participant is acceptable. 

I am more of an amateur in the question and just taking a look on a circom libraries am trying to figure out how to actually build such a circuit.

Comment: The relation between $P_k$ and $P_a$ is not explained. I assumed these form a key pair? If all users are honest, maybe an homomorphic commitment + a broadcast mechanism would be enough?

Comment: Yes they form a key pair. Pa is used for participants to send private messages to issuing authority. Pk is used by issuing authority to public sign messages. 

If due to some reason issuing authority stops operating participants want to be able to reconstruct the Pk, and use MPC for that. 
However it is a last resort and hence initially they just need to make sure that shares indeed construct back in to Pk without constructing the Pk itself.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Circom lib. But I have confidence that the circuit can be built by [Zokrates](https://zokrates.github.io/gettingstarted.html) toolbox. All you need is writing a function of which input is $P_k$ and output is $P_a$.